# ERROR TypeError: o.map is not a function on angular 4 prod build

Tags: angular, production

I have did some changes on an already exixting `angular 4` project. It is working goos on my local env. After I create the production build, I am getting the below error.

> ERROR TypeError: o.map is not a function
>       at kt (app.js?1571042006758:49)
>       at View_e_Host_0 (VM311 e_Host.ngfactory.js:5)
>       at i (app.js?1571042006758:7)
>       at bt (app.js?1571042006758:49)
>       at t.create (app.js?1571042006758:52)
>       at t.create (app.js?1571042006758:51)
>       at i.bootstrap (app.js?1571042006758:51)
>       at app.js?1571042006758:51
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at t._moduleDoBootstrap (app.js?1571042006758:51)

I am not getting from where it is triggering. Can someone help me on this? Thank you

Comment: it seems you call a ".map(...)" function somewhere in the code, on an object which is not an array. Can you please search your code for usages to see if that's the case?

Comment: @ForestG, Thanks for the suggestion. Will check and let you know. So a map() on object will trigger this issue?

Comment: check it out https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/160#issuecomment-343093906.  Looks like you  did `npm i` and some of your dependencies  get latest  version. For  quick fix you can try remove  `node_modules`  undo all changes at `package-lock.json` using  version control system and  run `npm ci`

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer for this issue after some search. The issue was with the versions of

@angular/common

and

@angular/compiler

my `common` version was 4.3.0 and `compiler` version was `4.7.0`. I downgraded `compiler` to 4.3.0 and the issue resolved.